# RouteLink empty Href

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routelink

Im using MVC3 with the Razor View Engine. I want to use a certain Route for a Href

the following is the Route registration, (the route seems to work as i can use the browser to directly use it)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AddItem",
    "{listAreaName}/{listSlug}/Add",
    new { controller = "List", action = "AddItem" }
    );
```

but the @Html.RouteLink just does not work. it returns an empty href for the link

Here are some of my attempts

```
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item", "AddItem", new { controller="List", action="AddItem", listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item1", "AddItem", new { controller = "List", listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item2", "AddItem", new { action = "AddItem", listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item3", "AddItem", new { controller = "list", action = "additem", listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item4", "additem", new { controller = "List", action = "AddItem", listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />

@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item5", "additem", new { listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item6", "AddItem", new { controller = "ListController", action = "AddItem", listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, listSlug = Model.Slug })<br />
```

if I miss out the route name, it generates working link, but its no in the right format

most of the material i found was for a preview release of v1. has this issue be sorted?

any idea's?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: look for a null in one of your objects you are passing. this will completely change the route. I sorted my issue by new-ing up a vanilla project and copying in the Route Maps, (d)enabling one by one.

Answer (score 2):

In the last route link you have a mistake, you should not use the `Controller` suffix:

```
@Html.RouteLink(
    "Add New Item6", 
    "AddItem", 
    new { 
        controller = "List", 
        action = "AddItem", 
        listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName, 
        listSlug = Model.Slug 
    }
)
```

As far as the others are concerned they all generate the following url: `/ListAreaName/Slug/Add` in ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM assuming you have the default routes setup and you have added the route shown in your question.

Comment: got desprite, started to try any combination to try an get it to work

Comment: there are a number of routes registered including the default one. If I remove the name of the route, it uses the default route.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

Only one element in your route can have a default omitted.  You don't have defaults for either listAreaName or listSlug.  See this question: [asp mvc routing with two optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061249/asp-mvc-routing-with-two-optional-parameters)

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AddItem",
    "{listAreaName}/{listSlug}/Add",
    new
    {
        controller = "List",
        action = "AddItem",
        listAreaName = "foo", // <-- add these
        listSlug = UrlParameter.Optional
    });
```

**Original**

Your route doesn't actually include the controller and action parameters.  Have you tried omitting them from the route values (they will be inferred when the route is decoded on the request).  The other thing that I would do is make sure that the model actually includes the `ListAreaName` and `Slug` values.

```
@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item",
                "AddItem",
                new
                {
                     listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName,
                     listSlug = Model.Slug 
                })<br />
```

Also, you really should be using CSS to style these as block level elements rather than adding a `<br/>` after it if at all possible.

```
<style>
   .block { display: block; }
</style>

@Html.RouteLink("Add New Item",
                "AddItem",
                new
                {
                     listAreaName = Model.ListAreaName,
                     listSlug = Model.Slug 
                },
                new { @class = "block" })
```

Comment: tried it "Add New Item5". also I have removed the htmlAttributes (where the css is) to simplify the situation

Comment: @dbones - I missed it before, but you have two optional elements in the route.  That won't work.  You'll need to update your route to provide a default for one of them.