# Identity 2.0 and Password Recovery - code = null in ResetPassword() Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently decided to use Account Confirmation and Password Recovery with ASP.NET Identity 2.0. As per the source file notes in a MVC new web application, I following the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity#email) on how to do this.

I'm having a problem with Password Recovery. Everything seems to work fine - user receives an email with a link to click. That link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:59655/Account/ResetPassword?userId=67502d68-67b9-4c45-8500-799e641eca06
&amp;code=9oHWvEJhyN5PaEclX06sUGgUMP6NkrCWfBTFsGg1xutPcDCzKxoO9SADPkVfz04Q84ZGNp%2F0
aTyL42f2MG98pBiBhF0fbTTYw4EepEpuT%2FotKSppriMZVTOVTMy6IrzF4jR8tzNaT7vtRKwwmcX2tskuDs7
Ew6DLJjPXCTa82uN4A1zAHGfLVnQ3gEmF%2BmvLwoeFkwB2SfvuLKqKAmMtMQ%3D%3D
```

When I click on the link I get a page that says:

```
Error.

An error occurred processing your request.
```

I set a breakpoint in the `/Account/ResetPassword(string code)` action. According to example, I've created that routine as follows:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id, string code)
{
    if (code == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
    return View();
}
```

On entry, `code` does equal `null` and so the error View is displayed.

I can see in Fiddler that the URL is intact according to how it was sent in the Email above. I'm not convinced there is anything wrong with the Password Recovery routines, but instead I think this is a similar issue I've experienced with other Controller Actions. That is, calling a Controller Action with a parameter named differently than the default (configured in RouteConfig.cs) causes a null in the Controller Action parameter.

For example, the default parameter in RouteConfig is `id`. If I change the name in the parameter to anything else it will contain a null:

```
http://example.com/Account/TestAction/testvalue

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult TestAction(string id)
{
    // id = testvalue
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult TestAction(string someid)
{
    // id = null
}
```

Ok, I don't understand why the above happens - but I have no problem accepting it.

Thing is, with respect to my question, the URL sent to the user in email contains 2 QueryString parameters - userId and Code. I've checked the sample application that shows how Account Confirmation and Password Recovery are coded and configured. There is nothing more than a default route set in RouteConfig.cs and the parameter name on the ResetPassword() Action is `string code`. Not only is it named different than `id`, but is also a single-parameter definition instead of 2 parameters I would expect `(string userId, string code)`.

Is this vague description a hint as to why `code = null` on entry to my `ResetPassword(string code)` Controller Action?

Is it true that a Controller Action parameter will always be null if RouteConfig.cs contains only the default configuration and the parameter has been named something other than `id`?

In the case of my ResetPassword Controller Action, how would a configuration be coded in RouteConfig.cs to work with calling it with the above QueryString containing userId and code?

**EDIT**

To test the theory that a route configuration was required in RouteConfig.cs, I added the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("ResetPassword",
    "{controller}/{action}/{userId}/{code}",
    new
        {
        controller = "Account",
        action = "ResetPassword",
        });
```

Clicking the link in the email resulted in:

```
HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

I also see in the detailed error description that `userId=` and `code=` were removed from the link and replaced with `/`. Essentially making them part of the URI instead of just QueryString parms. As a result of all of this, I don't think RouteConfig.cs configurations has anything to do with the problem.

Any suggestions? :S

Comment: well your problem is with routing. Take a look at. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061249/asp-mvc-routing-with-two-optional-parameters

Comment: I read the discussion and want to agree, but create a new project using MVC and try the ResetPassword functionality, you'll see it works. I checked the RouteConfig.cs in that project and it is just a default RouteConfig.cs with nothing special. If I create a config in RouteConfig.cs I get the double-escaping error from IIS, the QueryString disappears from the /Account/ResetPassword/... link sent via email. I understand what RouteConfig.cs does, but admit that I don't know exactly when a config is needed. Also, the default MVC project works with only `string code` as a parm to ResetPassword

Comment: @rwkiii If the link you posted above is indeed the URL that was entered in the browser, it would explain the problem as there are 2 issues... 1) the action expects a parameter named `id`, but is getting `userId`; 2) the URL appears to be HTML encoded, so the `&` is replaced with `&amp;` which mangles the `code` parameter name.

Comment: @rwkiii Try this link instead... `http://localhost:59655/Account/ResetPassword?id=67502d68-67b9-4c45-8500-799e641eca06
&code=9oHWvEJhyN5PaEclX06sUGgUMP6NkrCWfBTFsGg1xutPcDCzKxoO9SADPkVfz04Q84ZGNp%2F0
aTyL42f2MG98pBiBhF0fbTTYw4EepEpuT%2FotKSppriMZVTOVTMy6IrzF4jR8tzNaT7vtRKwwmcX2tskuDs7
Ew6DLJjPXCTa82uN4A1zAHGfLVnQ3gEmF%2BmvLwoeFkwB2SfvuLKqKAmMtMQ%3D%3D`

Comment: Anthony, yes! The link you provided works. On entry to ResetPassword the code parm has a code in it. I tried it with userId= and it worked that way also. The encoding may be coming from the Email package I'm using - NuGet Postal - it uses razor Views for templates. You gave me something to go off of and pointed me toward the problem. I'll try to figure out where it's being encoded - or how to decode it. I think @Html.Decode() might be a clue? I think you have the answer, but I won't be able to mark it as such unless you post other than a comment. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, `@Html.Raw`, not `@Html.Decode`. Even though @Html.Raw is doing some weird stuff to the URL and not working like I expected.