# Sending blank (null) values to my web api service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have a small function in my web api controller that looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IEmployee> GetEmployeesByFullName(string firstName, string lastName)
{
    var data = EmployeeDataProvider.GetEmployeeByFullName(firstName, lastName).ToList();
    return data;
}
```

I would like to be able to call it, with blank values in either first or lastname, but I'm not really able to do so. I would like to simply do it in the URL.

Is it not possible to somehow send `/GetEmployeesByFullName//Doe/`? Will I have to send it as post data, to send blank values?

If I do `/GetEmployeesByFullName//Doe/` I am told there is no matching action, on the controller.
Setting the parameters to optional, in my route, doesn't seem to make any difference. I simply do not hit this function.

Comment: i am not sure about this but you can try Nullable Types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: You can do `/GetEmployeesByFullName/` and `/GetEmployeesByFullName/Something/` but not `/GetEmployeesByFullName//Something`.

Comment: I think you will probably need additional routes for `/GetEmployeesByFirstName/John` and `/GetEmployeesByLastName/Doe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mostruash pointed out, you cannot do it with `/GetEmployeesByFullName//Something` since MVC doesn't support having two optional parameters. Only the last parameter can be optional (see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061249/asp-mvc-routing-with-two-optional-parameters)). If you want to do it by URL, why not simply state it as parameter:

```
/GetEmployeesByFullName?firstname=xxx&lastname=yyy
```

In this way, both can be empty:

```
/GetEmployeesByFullName?firstname=xxx // the method is called with lastname = null
/GetEmployeesByFullName?lastname=yyy // the method is called with firstname = null
```

If you have the use case that both parameters will be filled in, you could add the route like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "GetEmployees",
        url: "GetEmployeesByFullName/{firstname}/{lastname}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "GetEmployeesByFullName", firstname = UrlParameter.Optional, lastname = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```