# ASP.NET MVC Optional Page Parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Lets say I've two web addresses

```
http://www.example.com/page/one
http://www.example.com/page/one/subOne
```

How do I get them to be handled by the same controller.  At the moment the top address is being handled but the second is being handled by the postback function which doesn't render the page.

So for my routes config, I have

```
routes.MapRoute("PageRule", "page/{id}", new { Controller = "document", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
routes.MapRoute("Page2Rule","page/{id}/{misc}", new { Controller = "document", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

and in the controller I have

```
// GET: Document
public ActionResult Index(string id, string misc )
```

and

```
// Post
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postcomment(string gCaptcha,string txtName, string txtEmail, string txtMessage)
```

Comment: Try read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061249/asp-mvc-routing-with-two-optional-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this might be the only route you need:

```
routes.MapRoute("PageRule",
                "page/{id}/{misc}",
                new
                {
                    Controller = "document",
                    Action = "Index",
                    misc = UrlParameter.Optional
                });
```

Notice that there is no optional for `id`. The key is that both `id` and `misc` cannot be optional at the same time - only the last parameter in the route can be optional

Comment: Thanks, two things were wrong with my code, I noticed I had two rules when I only needed one which you pointed out.  Secondly, I had id as optional, it should misc that is optional.