# How to Redirect to specific action route

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

this is my custom route.but when I want to use `RedirectToAction("action","controller");` it cause error.
**No route in the route table matches the supplied values.**
I visited some related post but I could not solve it. How do I can fix it?

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{filter1}/{filter2}/{filter3}/{filter4}/{filter5}/{filter6}/{filter7}/{filter8}/{filter9}/",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Shop",
        action = "Category",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter2 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter3 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter4 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter5 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter6 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter7 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter8 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter9 = UrlParameter.Optional,
    }
);
```

Comment: How about trying `RedirectToAction("action", "controller", new { id = 0 })`? I think there's no route matches with action defined in `RedirectToAction`, you should create another mapping if you want to use multiple filters (or dynamic filters).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto tnx. it not worked. How can I create another mapping filter.

Comment: Is that route mapping the only one route in the `RouteConfig`? If my guess is right, there you should consider dividing routes into multiple mappings with different filters instead of using single default route for multiple filters.

Comment: Not related, but only the last parameter can be marked as `UrlParameter.Optional`

Comment: What you are trying will not work because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5061320/4228458).

Comment: @CodingYoshi, That has nothing to do with OP's issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem once with `RedirectToAction` and found out that you need a valid route registered that leads to that action. in your case, the error occurred because your optional parameter is more than expected amount.

I test code and it works :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{filter1}/{filter2}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Employees",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter1 = UrlParameter.Optional,
        filter2 = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);
```

if you want your own route you can use `[Route("")]` on top of your Action, at the first Add `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();` to `RegisterRoutes` method in `RouteConfig.cs`. After that do like below:

```
[Route("{TestEmployee}/{Index}/{id?}/{filter1?}/{filter2?}/{filter3?}/{filter4?}/{filter5?}/{filter6?}/{filter7?}/{filter8?}/{filter9?}")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //do something 
}
```

then you can `redirectToAction` :

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "TestEmployee" ,routeValues: null);
```

Comment: how about the situation that routeValues is not null!? I used a string like "1/3/def" (my parameters) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @mjyazdani Have you mapped correct MapRoute in your RouteConfig.cs ?!